# how to check two columns of different csv files in python?

Tags: python

row[1] and i[0] has movie id of two different csv files.How to compare the movie id of different files?

```
import csv
total=0
k=0
with open('R\genre_matrix2.csv')as Genre:
        csv_genre=csv.reader(Genre,delimiter=',')  

        with open('ratings1234.csv') as CsvFile:
            csv_rating=csv.reader(CsvFile,delimiter=',')
            for xy in range(1,611):
                for row in csv_rating:
                    if row[0] == xy:
                        i=float(row[2])
                        j=float(row[4])
                        k=i*j

                    for i in csv_genre: 

                        if(row[1] == i[0]):

                            val =  [x * k for x in i]
                            total+=val
                            print(row[0] + "\t" + total)
```

Comment: It would be useful for you to edit the question to explain a little more about the data format and your purpose. As the code stands it seems you are making specific assumptions about the order of the rows, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning!

have you thought about using about pandas and the `pandas.read_csv`-Function?

The code would look like the following

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('R\genre_matrix2.csv', delimiter=',')
df_2 = pd.read_csv('ratings1234.csv')

# looping through the files
# the following code is just a simple example
for i in range(1, df.shape[0]):
    # select row of first dataframe
    df_row = df.iloc[i, columns_index] 
    # select row of second dataframe
    df_row_2 = df_2.iloc[i, columns_index] 
    # compare
    df_row == df_row_2
```

This would maybe simplify your code.